# Drag connection type in jsPlumb

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable, jsplumb

I am making a network with help of draggable, droppable and jsPlumb. In my situation servers are drag and drop from list and after that connection is made using drag and drop according to type of cable.

In my code I have successfully implemented drag and drop of servers. I am facing problem in connection of servers on type of cable.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6yau576p/2/) for code.

HTML:

```
<body style="width: 100%; float: left;">
<div style="width:100%;" id="gridDiv">
    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; float: left;border:1px solid black;width:25%" >
        Server<ul style="list-style: none;" id="container">
            <li><img src="images/dedicated_server.png" id="img1" style="width:30px; height:30px"/></li>
            <li><img src="images/database.png" id="img2" style="width:30px; height:30px"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; float: left;border:1px solid black;width:25%" >
        Cable<ul style="list-style: none;" id="cableContainer">
            <li><img src="images/technology.png" id="img1" style="width:30px; height:30px" data-server="Cable"/></li>
            <li><img src="images/technology-2.png" id="img2" style="width:30px; height:30px" data-server="Cable"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width:70%; position: relative;float: right;border:1px solid black;" id="gridView">
    <!-- <div class="grid">hello</div> -->

    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

JQuery:

```
function createGrid() {

    var he = $('#gridView').height(),
        wi = $('#gridView').width();
    var x= 1;
    for (i=0; i< 12; i++) {
           for (var j=0; j < 12; j++) {
                var $newdiv = $('<div/>', {
                    "class": "grid",
                    text: '',
                    id: i + '##' + j,
                    x: i,
                    y: j
                });
                $('#gridView').append($newdiv);
               // x++;
           }
    } 
}

function handleDragStop( event, ui ) {
  var offsetXPos = parseInt( ui.offset.left );
  var offsetYPos = parseInt( ui.offset.top );
  console.log( "Drag stopped!\n\nOffset: (" + offsetXPos + ", " + offsetYPos + ")\n");
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
    createGrid();

    var original = true;
    var drop = false;

    applyDraggableOnList();

    applyDroppableOnGrid(); 

    applyDraggableOnCable();


    jsPlumb.ready(function() {
      console.log("jsPlumb is ready");
    });
});

var original = true;
var droppable = false;

function applyDraggableOnList(){
    $("#container > li > img").draggable({
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: "clone",
        containment: '#gridView',
        revert: "invalid",
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            original = false;
        },
        start: function( event, ui ) {
            original = true;   
            applyDraggableOnGrid();
        }
    });
}

function applyDraggableOnCable(){
    $("#cableContainer > li > img").draggable({
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: "clone",
        containment: '#gridView',
        revert: "invalid",
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            original = false;
        },
        start: function( event, ui ) {
            original = true;   
        }
    });
}

function applyDroppableOnList(){

}

function applyDraggableOnGrid(){

    $("#gridView").find('.draggableSpecific').draggable({
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: "original",
        containment: '#gridView',
        revert: "true",
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            original = false;
        },
        start: function( event, ui ) {
            original = true;   
        }
    });
}

var anEndpointDestination = {
    endpoint: "Dot",
    isSource: true,
    isTarget: true,
    maxConnections: 3,
    connector:[ "Bezier", { curviness:1 }],
    anchor:"AutoDefault"
};

var counter = 1; 
function applyDroppableOnGrid(){
    $("#gridView > div").droppable({
        activeClass: 'test',
        tolerance: 'fit',

        accept: function (elm) {
            var childLength = $(this).children().length;
            if(childLength == 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        },
       drop: function( event, ui) {

        console.log("(ui.draggable): " + ($(ui.draggable).hasClass("draggableSpecific")));
        if(!$(ui.draggable).hasClass("draggableSpecific") && $(ui.draggable).attr("data-server") != "Cable") {
           var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("src");
            var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");
            var currentObject = ui.draggable.clone();
            $(this).append(currentObject);
            $(this).find("img").addClass("draggableSpecific").addClass("window").removeClass("ui-draggable").attr('id', "jsPlumb_"+counter);
            counter++;

        } else if($(ui.draggable).attr("data-server") == "Cable") {
            console.log("Cable ");

              jsPlumb.connect({ uuids:[$(this).find("img").attr("id").getUuid(), $(this).find("img").attr("id").getUudi()] });

        } 

        jsPlumb.addEndpoint($(this).find("img").attr("id") ,{uuid:$(this).find("img").attr("id")});

        var anchorNode = $(this).find("img");

        /*jsPlumb.addEndpoint(
                anchorNode,
                anEndpointDestination
        );*/

        $(".draggableSpecific").draggable({
          cursor: 'move',
          containment: '#gridView',
          revert: "invalid"
        });
        jsPlumb.draggable($(this).find("img"));

      }
    });  
}
function deleteImage( $item ) {   
       console.log("Called deleteImage");
    }
```

My code snippet is looks like below : [image]

In this after dropping server as images in div I am not able to figure out that how to add connection using dragging from cable's list.